# Kaa node service fails to start mongodb and zookeeper

Tags: kaa

We are trying to setup a Single Node  Kaa server(version 0.10.0) in an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Followed the documentation given [here](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/)

We were unable to connect to the admin UI after starting the kaa node service.
On investigating further we could see that the Mongodb and zookeeper services were not started. So we manually started those services. After that we were able to connect to Kaa admin UI. Do we need any additional steps to get these service running on kaa-node start ?

Comment: Actually, both MongoDB and Zookeeper services should start up automatically upon system start (as well as kaa-node). Please check the services and system configuration for the possible causes for the services fail to start automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I setup kaaproject with the guide for my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS VM and Zookeeper was not running by default on my server also, so I had to install the deamon (which starts zookeeper also on startup):

```
sudo apt-get install zookeeperd
```

Check if zookeeper is running:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep 2181
```

This should result in an output like this:
[image]

With mongodb I had the problem, that there was not enough space available for the journal files. I fixed this by increasing the available disk space + setting `smallfiles=true` in the `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: The above solution worked for starting the zookeeper. So please modify the documentation given in the kaa server single node installation page.

Comment: This doesn't solved the original issue. So we have moved back to Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some troubles with configurations for services. Check if auto-startup is enabled for MongoDB / Zookeeper by the next command:

`$ systemctl is-enabled ${service-name}`

if you see this:

`$ disabled`

then auto-startup is disabled for specified service and you should try next in order to enable it:

`$ systemctl enable ${service-name}`